# Static HTML page that links to current Wordpress blog

Tags: html, wordpress

So, I currently have a WP blog installed. What I want to do is put a static HTML landing page at the root of the site and then a link to the blog. The HTML landing page does not look similar in theme and everything is hosted under the same domain.
How can I do this with this current structure?
I suppose I would have to somehow move the blog to /blog instead of the root?

Thanks.

Comment: You could do that or assign your WordPress install a Front Page (Settings / Reading) then edit `front-page.php` in the theme and paste in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what server you're running, you might not need to do anything. Certain servers, like Apache, have a DirectoryIndex which gives priority to .html files by default. So even if you had index.html and index.php in the same folder, it would load the index.html file.

You could also define the priority in an htaccess file or use the commenter above's suggestion of pasting the HTML into the index.php template and then making a "home" template and telling Wordpress to use that specific page as the homepage.

That being said, I would strongly recommend installing Wordpress in a sub-directory, such as "/blog" as you mentioned. Just as a fail-safe.